# Unique color ramp using factor with positive values below and above 0 using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to create a color ramp to plot in ggplot2 which is dependent on factors and numbers. I'll like the color ramp to be positive above and below. In my case I want to look at dominant gender population for each point.

```
##Create dataframe
DF1 <- data.frame(A=c("Female","Male","Male","Female","Male","Male"),
B=c(0.2,0.5,0.4,0.8,0.1,0.5), X <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6), Y <- c(1,4,3,2,3,1))
colnames(DF1)<-c("Sex", "Ratio", "X", "Y")
```

A sample plot of the data using ggplot just coloured it categorically not with a colour ramp.

```
##Basic plot using ggplot2
 ggplot()  + geom_point(data=DF1, aes(X,Y,colour=A),fill=B,alpha=0.8)
```

I'll like to create a colour ramp which is positive both sides of zero with one side is red and the other is blue based on "Sex". The colour intensity will be dependent on the "Ratio". What is the best way to do this please?

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 ways to do this:

**The Simple Way**: Set `color = Sex` and then use `alpha = Ratio` to adjust color saturation.

```
ggplot(DF1) +
    geom_point(aes(X, Y, color = Sex, alpha = Ratio)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('Male' = 'blue', 'Female' = 'red'))
```

[image]

This approach is simple and doesn't require changing variables, but you get a:

`Red -> Clear -> Blue` gradient instead of a `Red -> White -> Blue` gradient

---

**The Nicer Way**: If you want to keep a clearer `Red -> White -> Blue` gradient, you should combine `Sex` and `Ratio` into a new variable that describes your desired colors before going into `ggplot`.

Sex is a `factor`, so we can convert it into a `numeric` and then change it into a `-1:1` scale, rather than a `1:2` scale. Then we multiply it by `Ratio` to get a single numeric `sex_ratio` scale that incorporates both `Sex` and `Ratio`.

```
DF2 <- DF1 %>%
    mutate(sex_ratio = (as.numeric(Sex) * 2 - 3) * Ratio)
```

Now we can use `scale_color_gradient2` to make your blue-white-red gradient scale:

```
ggplot(DF2) +
    geom_point(aes(X, Y, color = sex_ratio)) +
    scale_color_gradient2(low = 'red', mid = 'white', high = 'blue')
```

[image]

---

If you really want `sex_ratio` to be a positive range from 0 to 1, just tweak the values and set the `midpoint` of the gradient manually:

```
DF3 <- DF1 %>%
    mutate(sex_ratio = ((as.numeric(Sex) * 2 - 3) * Ratio + 1) / 2)

DF3$sex_ratio
[1] 0.40 0.75 0.70 0.10 0.55 0.75

ggplot(DF3) +
    geom_point(aes(X, Y, color = sex_ratio)) +
    scale_color_gradient2(low = 'red', mid = 'white', high = 'blue', midpoint = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @divibisan. However, this method only vconverts the dsiplay to a ramp. Of course, I can edit the numbers on the colour ramp so that it's positive below 0 after exporting from R. Is there a way to output directly from ggplot2 with positive numbers above and below 0?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to stick with new labels with amendment to the answer by @divisan. So, the first step would be to do a trial plot to determine the number breaks and then plot properly.

```
  DF1 <- data.frame(A=c("Female","Male","Male","Female","Male","Male"),
              B=c(0.2,0.5,0.4,0.8,0.1,0.5), X <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6), Y <- c(1,4,3,2,3,1))
colnames(DF1)<-c("Sex", "Ratio", "X", "Y") 

#Edit table to ensure both genders are negative or positive
 DF2 <- DF1 %>% mutate(sex_ratio = (as.numeric(Sex) * 2 - 3) * Ratio)

#Plot to view data range and number breaks of color ramp
ggplot()  + geom_point(data=DF2, aes(X,Y,colour=sex_ratio),alpha=0.8) +
scale_color_gradient2(low = 'red', mid = 'white', high = 'blue',midpoint=0)
```

[image]

```
#To plot fully
ggplot() + theme_bw  + geom_point(data=DF2, aes(X,Y,colour=sex_ratio ,size=Ratio),alpha=0.8) +
scale_color_gradient2(low = 'red', mid = 'white', high = 'blue',midpoint=0,
     labels = c("0.75","0.50","0.25","0","0.25","0.50"), name= "Gender")
```

[image]