# R, ggplot2, specify colors for each level based on another column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use ggplot2 to show how the accuracy on a category-learning task change across the months. So 'Month' is x-axis, and 'Accuracy' is y-axis. I also have another column 'block' that goes with 'Cat'(i.e., category). 'Cat' has 2 levels, 'II' and 'RD', and each of these levels have 'block1','block2','block3' and 'block4'. So I want to have 8 lines showing the interaction between 'block' and 'Cat', conceptually these would be 8 conditions (RD & block1; II & block1…etc). I want the lines for RD to be in 1 color, but different shades across the blocks; same with the lines for II (i.e., same color, different shades across blocks).

I was only able to create the graph that use different color for the two categories, but unable to further specify the shades for individual blocks, how should I do that?

[image]

```
MonthPlot<-ggplot(summary_Month, aes(Month, accuracy, 
        color= Cat, group=interaction(Cat, block))) + 

geom_line() + 



labs(x= "Month", y= "Accuracy") +
scale_colour_hue(name="Category Type",   
                 breaks=c("RD", "II"),
                 labels=c("Rule_Defined", 
                          "Information_Integration")) +                   
ggtitle("Performance change across Months") +

scale_x_discrete(labels = c("01_Jan" = "Jan", "02_Feb" = "Feb",
                          "03_Mar" = "Mar", "04_Apr" = "Apr",
                          "05_May" = "May", "09_Sep" = "Sept",
                          "10_Oct" = "Oct", "11_Nov" = "Nov"))+
theme(plot.title= element_text(hjust= 0.5)) +

ylim(.5, .85) +                        
theme_light() +

theme(legend.justification=c(1,0),
      legend.position=c(1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52265757/unique-color-ramp-using-factor-with-positive-values-below-and-above-0-using-ggpl/52266413#52266413

Comment: I'd suggest setting `alpha = block` or merging `Cat` and `block` into a new combined variable, which you set colors based on.

Comment: Can you please provide the table as data instead of screenshot? I'd rather not retype. Try `dput(summary_Month)` and replace the screenshot with code like `summary_Month =    [whatever came out of dput....]`